# Installing/updating EclipseLink in Eclipse Dali

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, dali

I'm currently using `Eclipse Dali` with `EclipseLink 2.5.2`.

Now I want to change to version `EclipseLink 2.7.5`, but I'm unable to find out how to setup Dali for new EclipseLink versions.

The JPA project dialog only shows `EclipseLink 2.5.2` as a possible choice for the platform:

[image: Eclipse Dali Project Settings]

So I guess, I must download and install a new persistence platform so I'm able to select `EclipseLink 2.7.5` from this dialog? Note that I already downloaded the zip archive for `EclipseLink 2.7.5` - is it perhaps somehow possible to point Dali to this archive? Or is it necessary to manually remove `EclipseLink 2.5.2` from the project's classpath and instead add the corresponding jar files for `EclipseLink 2.7.5`?

I'm sure that I'm missing something very obvious here since updating the persistence platform is certainly a common and easily done task... any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update to `EclipseLink 2.7.5` by manually adding a new user library and then selecting this library in the JPA project dialog:

[image]

In the user library I simply added all jar files of `EclipseLink 2.7.5` in the EclipseLink jlib folder.

Note that the folder of the library must not be a subfolder of the Eclipse project folder, otherwise Eclipse Dali will complain with the following error message (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56111116/3270595)):

> The class 'javax.persistence.Convert' is required to be in the
>   selected libraries

Note also that for some reason it was necessary to move the `EclipseLink 2.7.5` user library to the top of the dependency list in the Eclipse Run Configurations dialog.

I will happily accept any other answer that provides a more convenient way of updating EclipseLink.